# Is there any query to generate dump of databases in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there any query to generate dump of databases? I want to generate the dump without gui, especially for mssql? I don't want to use any import/export tools. In short, I need to script all the objects in db with the query

Comment: Are you asking how to cursor through all table objects and dump the data to external files?  What RDBMS is it?  Do you have administrative rights (e.g., to run BCP commands)?

Comment: yes i am asking to do this job but with the query, and not in the external file, i just want a result set

Comment: What database is it -- SQL Server, Oracle, Sybase, MySQL, etc.?  SQL Server has a table called `sys.tables` that lists all of the tables.  Don't know the name of the systable for the other databases.  I'll provide an example for SQL Server, you can adapt for other databases...

Comment: Sorry -- missed the `mssql` part of your original question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for SQL Server.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(255), @table sysname

declare cr cursor local for
  select name from sys.tables where type = 'U'

open cr
fetch next from cr into @table

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @sql = 'select * from [' + @table + ']'
  exec sp_executesql @sql
  fetch next from cr into @table
end

close cr
deallocate cr
```

The idea is to enumerate the 'user' tables and create dynamic SQL to `select *` from each...